# Troubleshooting Socket.io Connectivity Issues on Mobile App

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am working with socket.io, and the issue I'm facing is that the socket is not initializing for new users. Upon debugging, I found that the socket does not disconnect from the last user who logged off from the app. Consequently, the socket remains connected on the server from the last user.

Below is my code:

```
class WebSockets {

  constructor(opts) {
    // Save a reference to our dependency.
    const { socket_io, config, jsonwebtoken, webSocketHelpers, userMessagesService, userGroupsService, query } = opts;

    this.io = socket_io
    this.config = config
    this.jwt = jsonwebtoken
    this.webSocketHelpers = webSocketHelpers
    this.userMessagesService = userMessagesService
    this.userGroupsService = userGroupsService
    this.query = query
  }


  users = [];

  customers = [];


  // ************************************************************* HELPER FUNCTIONS START

  initialize = (server,) => {
    this.io = this.io(server, {
      serveClient: false,
      pingInterval: 120000,
      pingTimeout: 60000,
      cookie: false,
      reconnection: true,  // Enable reconnection
      reconnectionAttempts: 10,  // Number of reconnection attempts
      reconnectionDelay: 1000,  // Delay between reconnection attempts (in milliseconds)
      reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,  // Maximum delay between reconnection attempts
      secure: true,
      transports: ["websocket"]
    })
    this.io.use(this.authenticateSocket);

    this.io.of('/').on('connection', this.connection)
  }


  connection = (client) => {


    client.on("disconnect", () => {

      this.users = this.users.filter(el => el.socketId != client.id)

      let userExists = this.users.some(el => el.userId == client.userId);

      if (!userExists && !client.isAdmin) {
        //remove user from queue
        //make users
        this.webSocketHelpers.removeUserFromQueue(client.clientId, client.userId)

        //add to people to logout + plus their time since last activity in redis
      }
    });

    async function authenticateToken(jwt, config) {
      const token = client.handshake.query.token;
      return await jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwt').secret)

    }

    client.on("userMessages", async (args) => {
      let credentials = await authenticateToken(this.jwt, this.config);

      args["clientId"] = credentials.client;
      args["sender_id"] = credentials.actor;
      args["userId"] = credentials.actor;

      const data = await this.userMessagesService.create(args);

      this.portalMessages(args["userId"], data);
    });

    client.on("createGroup", async (args) => {
      let credentials = await authenticateToken(this.jwt, this.config);

      args["clientId"] = credentials.client;
      args["creator_id"] = credentials.actor;

      const data = await this.userGroupsService.createGroup(args);

      this.createGroup(credentials.actor, data);
    });

    client.on("readMessages", async (args) => {
      let credentials = await authenticateToken(this.jwt, this.config);

      args["clientId"] = credentials.client;
      args["userId"] = credentials.actor;

      const data = await this.userMessagesService.changeStatus(args);
    });

    client.on("updateGroup", async (args) => {
      let credentials = await authenticateToken(this.jwt, this.config);
      let data = null;
      args["clientId"] = credentials.client;
      args["userId"] = credentials.actor;
      if (args["type"] == "add") {
        data = await this.userGroupsService.addMember(args);
      } else if (args["type"] == "remove") {
        data = await this.userGroupsService.removeMember(args);
      } else if (args["type"] == "update") {
        data = await this.userGroupsService.update(args);
      }

      this.groupUpdated(credentials.actor, data);
    });
  };

  authenticateSocket = async (socket, next) => {
    try {
      const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
      const { client, actor, max_token_count, customer_id, customer_number } = await this.jwt.verify(token, this.config.get('jwt').secret);

      if (actor && client && max_token_count) {
        socket.clientId = client;
        socket.userId = actor;
        socket.admin = (max_token_count == -1);

        this.users.push({
          socketId: socket.id,
          userId: actor,
          clientId: client,
          admin: max_token_count == -1
        });

        next();
      } else if (customer_number) {
        this.customers.push({
          socketId: socket.id,
          customer_number
        });

        next();
      }


    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERROR==========================================", err)
    }
  }
  getClientsByUserId = (userId) => {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.userId == userId)
  }
  getClientsByClientId = (clientId) => {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.clientId == clientId)
  }
  getAdminClientsByClientId = (clientId) => {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.clientId == clientId && user.admin)
  }
  getByCustomerNumber = (customerNumber) => {
    return this.customers.filter(customer => customer.customer_number == customerNumber)
  }
  // ************************************************************* HELPER FUNCTIONS END



  newMessage = async (userId) => {

    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newMessage", { newMessage: true })
      })
    }
  }


  newMessageFromUser = (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newConversation", data)
      })
    }
  }
  newConversationMessage = (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)
    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newConversationMessage", data)
      })
    }
  }
  updateMessageStatus = (userId, messageId, stateId) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("updateMessageStatus", { messageId, stateId })
      })
    }
  }
  removeConversation = (data) => {
    if (data && data.userId) {
      let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(data.userId)
      if (clients && clients.length) {
        clients.map(client => {
          this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("removeConversation", { ...data, userId: undefined })
        })
      }
    }
  }
  historyOnTop = (clientId, customerId) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByClientId(clientId)
    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("historyOnTop", { customerId })
      })
    }
  }
  iAmOnline = (userId, isOnline) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)
    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("iAmOnline", { isOnline })
      })
    }
  }
  updateCustomerMessagesByClientId = (clientId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("updateCustomerMessages", data)
      })
    }
  }

  updateCustomerMessages = (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("updateCustomerMessages", data)
      })
    }
  }


  updateHistoryConversation = (clientId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("updateHistoryConversation", data)
      })
    }
  }
  updateOnGoingConversation = (clientId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("updateOnGoingConversation", data)
      })
    }
  }

  onGoingConversation = (clientId, data, addOrRemove) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("onGoingConversation", { ...data, addOrRemove })
      })
    }
  }
  newOngoingConversationMessage = (clientId, agentId, userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newOngoingConversationMessage_${agentId}_${userId}`, data)
      })
    }
  }

  newMessageForOngoing = (clientId, customerId, a_id) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newMessageForOngoing`, { customerId, a_id })
      })
    }
  }
  updateOnGoingMessageStatus = (clientId, agentUserId, customerId, messageId, stateId) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newOngoingConversationMessageStatus_${agentUserId}_${customerId}`, { messageId, stateId })
      })
    }
  }


  newOnGoingConversationCount = (clientId) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newOnGoingConversationCount`, { getData: true })
      })
    }
  }

  newMessageNotification = (userId) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newMessageNotification`, { newMessage: true })
      })
    }
  }
  agentOnline = async (clientId, agentId, online) => {

    let data = {
      agentId,
      active: online
    }
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    clients.map(client => {
      this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("agentsOnline", data)
    })
  }
  getConnectedUsers = async (cb) => {
    let users = this.users.map(el =>
      el.userId
    ).filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t === v)) === i)

    cb(users)
  }

  newUnassignedMessage = (clientId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getAdminClientsByClientId(clientId)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`new_Unassigned_Message`, data)
      })
    }
  }


  portalMessages = async (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId);

    let members = [];
    let group_members = false;

    if (data[0].receiver_id.includes("group")) {
      [members] = await this.query.final([
        "user_groups",
        "get_list",
        undefined,
        undefined,
        'group_members',
        `group_id = '${data[0].receiver_id}'`
      ]);

      members.group_members.map(m => {
        let temp = null

        temp = this.users.filter(u => u.userId == m)
        if (temp[0] != undefined) {
          clients.push(...temp)
        }
      })
    } else {
      let arr = this.users.filter(u => u.userId == data[0].receiver_id)
      clients.push(...arr)
    }
    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(async (client) => {
        if (client.userId == data[0].receiver_id || client.userId != data[0].sender_id) {

          data[0].type = "inbound"
        } else {
          data[0].type = "outbound"
        }

        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`portalMessages`, data)
      })
    }

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(async (client) => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`portalMessages`, data);
      });
    }
  };

  createGroup = async (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId);

    let members = [];

    if (data.group_id.includes("group")) {
      [members] = await this.query.final([
        "user_groups",
        "get_list",
        undefined,
        undefined,
        "group_members",
        `group_id = '${data.group_id}'`,
      ]);

      members.group_members.map((m) => {
        let temp = null;

        temp = this.users.filter((u) => u.userId == m);
        if (temp[0] != undefined) {
          clients.push(temp);
        }
      });
    }

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map((client) => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`groupCreated`, data);
      });
    }
  };

  groupUpdated = async (userId, data) => {
    let clients = this.getClientsByUserId(userId);
    console.log(data, "dataas");
    console.log(userId, "useridddd");
    let members = [];
    let group_members = false;

    [members] = await this.query.final([
      "user_groups",
      "get_list",
      undefined,
      undefined,
      "group_members",
      `group_id = '${data[0].group_id}'`,
    ]);

    members.group_members.map((m) => {
      let temp = null;

      temp = this.users.filter((u) => u.userId == m);
      if (temp[0] != undefined) {
        clients.push(temp);
      }
    });

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(async (client) => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`groupUpdated`, ...data);
      });
    }
  };

  portalOnline = (clientId, data) => {

    let clients = this.getClientsByClientId(clientId);

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(async (client) => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`portalOnline`, data);
      });
    }

  }

  newCustomerMessage = (customerNumber, data) => {
    let clients = this.getByCustomerNumber(customerNumber)
    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newCustomerMessage", data)
      })
    }
  }

  newMessageNotificationFromClient = (customerNumber) => {
    let clients = this.getByCustomerNumber(customerNumber)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newMessageNotificationFromClient", { newMessage: true })
      })
    }
  }

  newCustomerMessageForOngoing = (clientId, customerNumber) => {
    let clients = this.getByCustomerNumber(customerNumber)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit(`newCustomerMessageForOngoing`, { customerNumber, clientId })
      })
    }
  }

  newMessageFromClient = (customerNumber, data) => {
    let clients = this.getByCustomerNumber(customerNumber)

    if (clients && clients.length) {
      clients.map(client => {
        this.io.to(client.socketId).emit("newConversationFromClient", data)
      })
    }
  }

}

module.exports = WebSockets;`
```

I would appreciate assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.